# Can't remove file based variables

Tags: gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

It looks like this error output from gitlab runner isn't well documented on the Internet so far so I'm starting a topic. Error output:

```
Step 11/13 : RUN chown -R node /usr/src/app/node_modules
 ---> Running in d9cb1a93d908
WARNING: Error while executing file based variables removal script  error=context canceled job=1 project=0
ERROR: Failed to cleanup volumes
ERROR: Job failed: execution took longer than 30m0s seconds

FATAL: execution took longer than 30m0s seconds
```

this is coming from gitlab runner installed locally on Ubuntu machine.
Any suggestions as to how to troubleshoot this error ?

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:16-alpine

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

ENV PATH /usr/src/app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

COPY package.json /usr/src/app/package.json
COPY package-lock.json /usr/src/app/package-lock.json
RUN mkdir /usr/src/app/node_modules
RUN mkdir /usr/src/app/node_modules/.cache
RUN npm config set unsafe-perm true  # to avoid permission problems when accessing .cache dir later on
RUN npm ci --loglevel=error
RUN npm i -g --silent --loglevel=error
RUN chown -R node /usr/src/app/node_modules
USER node

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Answer (score 4):

I don't think this is related to gitlab, you are overwriting the owner of every  dependency in your project, with nodejs those tend to grow exponentially.

[image: node modules]

You didn't post your `Dockerfile`, but this would be a matter of just rewriting in the following way:

```
FROM node:16-alpine

ENV PATH /home/node/app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

# Create a directory for the project, change the owner and group
# to it, but do this before installing anything in the node_modules
# directory, to avoid timeouts.
RUN mkdir -p /home/node/app/node_modules \
    && mkdir -p /home/node/app/node_modules/.cache \
    && chown -R node:node /home/node/app

# Change to a workdir that can be owned by the 'node' user
WORKDIR /home/node/app

# Copying the lockfiles to make them cached by Docker, 
# also sets the right permissions at the same time
COPY --chown=node:node package*.json ./

# to avoid permission problems when accessing .cache dir later on
RUN npm config set unsafe-perm true
RUN npm ci --loglevel=error \
    && npm i -g --silent --loglevel=error

# Now, change to the node user and install your deps
USER node

# Copy the remaining files and make sure to set the user/group
# right, to avoid permission issues
COPY --chown=node:node . .

RUN npm install

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Comment: I've added Dockerfile I'm using to the question. Can you please review ? I don't think there's a major problem there but I've been wrong before.

Comment: @Mark Nice, I've updated my answer to match the Dockerfile provided.